# How to correctly pass parameters in POST request to WebRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to create a requester on the authorization form, if the data is correct - a redirect to another page will occur, if not correct - will return the authorization form.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.request.com/");
request.Proxy = new WebProxy (new Uri ("http://myproxy.ru"));
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application / x-www-form-urlencoded";

NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString (String.Empty);

outgoingQueryString.Add ("_method", "POST");
outgoingQueryString.Add ("data [User] [email]", "email@my.ru");
outgoingQueryString.Add ("data [User] [password]", "QWErty01");

byte [] byteArray = new ASCIIEncoding (). GetBytes (outgoingQueryString.ToString ());

request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close ();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();

dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();

reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

In responseFromServer I find exactly the form of authorization, as if the data is not correct.

At the same time, the same JS request is processed for

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://cora-request.com/',
  data: { '_method': 'POST', "data[User][email]": "email@my.ru", "data[User][password]": "QWErty01" },
  success: function(response){ console.log(response) }
});
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Aside from the question, you could use "using" in above code? for Reader, DataStream.

Comment: Did you try to catch the request in Fiddler and see what request is being pushed?

Comment: I am not sure but it could be related to Encoding as well i.e:

ASCIIEncoding you should try UTF8 encoding

Comment: You have specified `request.ContentType = "application / x-www-form-urlencoded"`. Thus, you have to Url-Encode you data before sending it. You can use `WebUtility.UrlEncode()` for this.